# Is the network address of the DHCP offer, the IP of the interface that requests it?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

Suppose the DHCP offer is 118.112.200.14 / 24, which is acknowledged, what is the IP that the interface chooses as its own. I would think it is 118.112.200.0, the network address after applying the subnet. That would be the IP associated with the interface, like in the routing table for example. Is that correct? Or would it be another one like 118.112.200.1 with the remaining 256-1-2 being available for a DHCP from that node?

Comment: so the IP that the DHCP offers IS the IP assigned to the interface. I'm not clear on the distinction you are trying to make. from the combination of the IP address and the subnet mask, the interface can calculate the Network ID (118.112.200.0), the Broadcast IP (118.112.200.255), and the address range from those two pieces of information (.1 - .254). yes, that network has room for 254 hosts, that DHCP can pass out if that is what you are asking.

Comment: "the interface chooses as its own" are you asking about the DHCP client's interface, or about the DHCP server's? (If you're asking about the client, why do you think the address would be different from the offered address?)

Comment: @FrankThomas The interface has been offered a range right? Now the interface itself has to have an IP right? And like pass on the remaining to the nodes that lie below it, right? Now in the offered range, I would think that 118.112.200.0 is the network address and can't be the IP of the interface. So it has to be something else, which is 118.112.200.128. The remaining IP addresses would be 118.112.200.0/25 and 118.112.200.128/25. I am getting confused here...

Comment: No, it has been offered an address, not a range.  it is literally telling your interface to configure itself with the single address 118.112.200.14, and then to confirm that it did so. there is no passing on to anyone else. yes the netmask for the interface is part of what is sent by the DHCP server, and it allows the host to calculate the shape of the network from its perspective, but DHCP isn't handing out blocks of addresses, just individual ones.

Comment: @FrankThomas Thank you. Is there any difference between the DHCP offering 118.112.200.14 / 24 and 118.112.200.15 / 24 . From the DHCP's server's perspective, it is the range that matters right, because the subnet address for both will be the same. Even if they are expected to have the IP's offered, does it make any practical difference what the IP's are that the DHCP client chooses ultimately. I probably am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: no not really. it depends on the implementation I'm sure, but a DHCP server has an address pool to pull from (a range) and they generally assign addresses sequentially, starting with the lowest address not associated with a persistent pairing (based on MAC address) or a lease the server remembers. It doesn't HAVE to work that way, it could assign them randomly or in reverse order, but I've always noticed them counting up from the lowest address in the pool. it doesn't really matter as long as the devices all get unique IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question and your followup comments, it seems you've mistakenly assumed that the presence of a subnet mask in the DHCP Offer somehow indicates that a range of addresses is being offered. That's not the case.

A single IP address is being offered, but the subnet mask must be communicated as well. This is because all hosts must know their subnet mask in order to know which addresses are local to the subnet, so that they can send packets to those hosts directly (after doing an ARP request to find the destination host's link-layer address), and also so they know which addresses are not local, and thus must be sent via the default gateway (i.e. they must be addressed, at the link layer, to the default gateway's link-layer address, while at the network/IP layer, they are still addressed to the intended destination IP address). In addition, the combination of the single IP address and subnet mask allows the host to determine the broadcast address of the subnet.